# extjs store.load not populating, possibly root object issue?

Tags: extjs, model, store

I am having trouble loading my first ExtJS store.

```
        var testStore = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('myUserStoreID');
        testStore.load({

        callback: function (records, operation, success) {

            testStore.each(function (record) {
                debugger;
                var task = record.data.description;
                console.log(task);
            });

            //debugger;
            //var x2 = operation._response;
            //var x3 = x2.responseText;
            //var x4 = Ext.decode(x3);
            ////var x3 = Ext.JSON.decode(operation);
            ////var x2 = Ext.decode(operation.response);

            //console.log(testStore);

        }
    });
```

In debugger I can see the correct data if I drilldown into operation._response.responseText, but the records are blank.  So I know it just has to do with my code.  If I use the Ext.decode it does return an object.  What am I doing wrong that the return data automatically populates my store.

Here is a picture of the object in fiddler.
[image: fiddler]

here is the Model I am trying to use... I know it doesn't have all the fields yet.

```
Ext.define('ExtApplication1.model.UserModel', {
extend: 'ExtApplication1.model.Base',

requires: ['ExtApplication1.model.Base'],

fields: [
    /*
    The fields for this model. This is an Array of Ext.data.field.Field definition objects or simply the field name.
    If just a name is given, the field type defaults to auto.  For example:
    */
    { name: 'UserID',     type: 'int' },
    { name: 'UserName',      type: 'string' },
    { name: 'password',    type: 'string' },
    { name: 'Email',   type: 'string' },
    { name: 'GroupID' }

],

proxy: {

    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'http://localhost:49537/api/user/gettargetuser/xxx/xxx',

    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        rootProperty: 'JSON'
    }

}
```

Here is my User class in webapi
[image: userclasswebapi]

here is the MainModel.js where I create stores

```
Ext.define('ExtApplication1.view.main.MainModel', {
extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',

alias: 'viewmodel.main',

data: {
    name: 'ExtApplication1',
    appName: xxx,
    appHeaderIcon: '<span class="fa fa-desktop fa-lg app-header-logo">',
    footer: 'Copyright - xxx- x
},

stores: {
        sessionListByInterest: {
            model: 'MainMenuListModel',
            autoLoad: false     //was true
        },
        myUserStore: {
            model: 'UserModel',
            storeId: 'myUserStoreID',
            autoLoad: false
        },
```

Comment: Your JSON attribute names don't match with the  field names in your extjs model.  for example, you have 'email' in JSON but 'Email' as field name in the model. If you fix this, does it work?

Comment: @AmolKatdare very weird, they actually do match... at least the email does.  I attached a picture of the webapiClass for User... email does show as "Email". so at least that prop does match.

Comment: does this have something to do with my rootProperty?

Comment: also, in my ExtJS model, do I have to have the navigation properties that are defined in my webapi... as you can see above, I have public virtual Group Group, but I do NOT have this in my EXTJS Model

Comment: Please show the code of your `myUserStoreID` store. If it derives from `JsonStore`, the store by default has its own proxy, which is always prefered over the proxy defined in the model.

Comment: Hi @Alexander, I added the code to the end of my original post to show where I create myUserStoreID.  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the store expects rootProperty to contain an array of records, while you are only delivering a single record.

If you want to only load a single record, which is not in an array, you would have to use the static [`model.load()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1-classic/Ext.data.Model.html#static-method-load) function.

Or you can change your API endpoint from `User JSON` to `List<User> JSON` (or `IEnumerable<User>` or `ICollection<User>` or `User[]`...), even if you intend to only return a single user. Doesn't matter how many records there are in the JSON array, but the array is expected by ExtJS store.

Comment: let me check that... how do I know what to put in the proxy for rootProperty?

Comment: so I changed my call to return a few items and you are correct... it worked!  thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: one last thing about this, I posted my sql diagram above.  In my webapi I have classes for all those tables (10 classes).  In ExtJS I only have 1 model of user.  Now when I do this store.load of users, when I look at the record/object in webbrower debugger I can drill down into all 10 classes... all without have the classes in ExtJS.  I was under the impression if I had 10 webapi classes, I would have to have 10 extjs classes.  What am I not getting here?

Comment: The webbrowser is javascript, JSON is javascript object notation. WebAPI serializes all objects in a hierarchy, so the deserialized JSON object contains all of them. But this does not mean that ExtJS can work with all of them. All the specialties of ExtJS models (loading into a form, tracking changes etc.) do not work with the submodels as long as you don't create the full ExtJS object hierarchy. I don't know how to do that and have only used flat objects in ExtJS for now.

Comment: thanks @Alexander... guess that makes sense.  Basically if I want to use the features of extjs I need to have ExtJS models.  appreciate all the help!